# Filtering a queryset across a foreign key, using a parameter e.g. as argument from the view

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I'm trying to build a flexible queryset that gives a result size based on parameters I use, but currently I'm only accessing that data from across a foreign key. Here's the setup.

My first table is a set of "blog posts" - the model is pretty self explanatory:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.TextField()
```

The second is a table that holds all the images for all the posts in a one-to-many relationship:

```
class BlogImageSeqFilter(models.Manager):
    def get_querySet(self):
        ## slice the first three images with sequence between 1 and 3
        return self.filter(sequence__gte=1, sequence__lte=3)[:3]

class BlogImage(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgFolder, blank=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    objects = BlogImageSeqFilter() ## Custom Manager class BlogImageSeqFilter
```

(The manager method comes in a little later in my question - I don't even know if using it has been the right approach so far...)

In my view, the set of blog posts is included contextually in the rendering of the html tmeplate:

```
def blogPage(request, proj):
    ## Limit to the newest 5 posts
    blogs = project.blogpost_set.all().order_by("-dateStamp")[:5]
    return render(request, 'blog/blogPage.html', {"blogs":blogs})
```

So in my template, I am displaying each blog post in a separate container, and including the set of images relevant to that blog using blogimage_set. A simplification of what I've got so far would be:

```
{% for post in blogs %}
    <div>
        {{post.title}}
        {{post.post}}
        {% for image in post.blogimage_set.get_querySet %}
            <img src="yada yada {{image.img}} yada yada></img>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, what I am stuck on. I want to change the model and the view, so that I can pass an argument somehow to limit the number of items in each post (as I understand it you can't really pass arguments from the template backwards, unless you start faffing with custom template tags which I don't want to do in this case because I'm sure there is a better way of doing it, and I want to learn that way.)

I want something flexible enough that I could re-use the blog images somewhere else, using a different parameter to represent the number of images returned. But it's not as simple as "Give me the first x images in the table".

Say I upload 10 images, I will assign them all sequence #s from 1-10 (hence the 'sequence' field in the model). But that sequence might not be in the same order that I uploaded. So overall I want to be able to choose in a given view which x images from the set of 10 will appear on that blog post. "Give me images between seq #1 and #3" or "Give me 5 images starting from seq #4" or something.

My first incremental attempt towards achieving this functionality was to create the BlogImageSeqFilter Manager and its method which gives a limited queryset of three items having sequence between 1 and 3.

Changing the model (or rather the Manager/its method) to accept an argument seems like the simple bit. But what I can't figure out is how to modify the view and the template to use parameters, in such a way that I can include "blogImages" in the render's context while still displaying them in the template as shown above ("for each post in the given blog ...do some html and... for each x images for that post...do some more html").

I appreciate that changing up the images displayed in a conventional "blog post" after the initial posting isn't a context that makes much sense - but as mentioned I want that flexibility to maybe use elsewhere, or reuse the code for something else at a later date. And I have a feeling I'm stuck because of a knowledge/skill gap or a wider problem with the way I'm currently working, so might as well identify it here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things a bit. If you want to control how many images you display in a particular context, you can just [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) the image queryset, at the point of use.

So in your template you would do something like this to render the first three images:

```
{% for image in post.blogimage_set.all|slice:":3" %}
    <img src="yada yada {{image.img}} yada yada></img>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so this will only fetch the first three images from your database.

If somewhere else you want to use more/fewer images, you just slice the queryset differently. I don't think you need a custom model manager to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you, yes in a simpler case slicing would be good enough. But this is overcomplicated (criticism accepted) by design. I want to be able to specify exactly which images should be displayed based on a sequence #. If I change my mind on which images to show, I just rearrange the sequence #s in admin later on.

I have edited to try and clarify my question a little, since I didn't make the purpose of the sequence field explicit enough before.

Comment: In that case a custom template tag seems to be the way to go. I can't see how else you can pass all that information from the template.

Comment: I don't want to pass it all from the template backwards though. I thought that trying to do logic at the template layer is generally bad practice (or just not possible in a lot of cases)? I wanted the model and the view to figure out between them which images to pass to the template - so that the same model and/or views could be used for different templates, resulting in slightly different sets of images?

Comment: Given the level of flexibility that you want, I can't really think of a solution that doesn't involve a custom template tag. Let's say your view defined which sequence it wants to display images in - you still need a way to pass that information to your model queryset - a template tag would let you take the view context and fetch the appropriate queryset.